# Using pyrcl for trace32

Tags: python, trace32, lauterbach

Iam trying to remotely control the trace32 and trying to add commands from pyhton, in this process i have to set break point using python but i cannot set as its saying the function name is not defined (i have already flashed my hex and elf) other functions such as symbol name is working well

```
import lauterbach.trace32.rcl as t32
dbg = t32.autoconnect()
self = dbg.symbol.query_by_name(name='ComMainFunctionTx')
print(self) 
bp = dbg.breakpoint.set(*"ComComMainFunctionTx ",**())
```

This is my output iam not understanding what to keep here for mapping

```
ComComMainFunctionTx P:0x801bacf0 930
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\test hello.py", line 24, in <module>
    bpt=dbg.breakpoint.set(*"ComComMainFunctionTx ",**())
TypeError: lauterbach.trace32.rcl._rc._breakpoint.BreakpointService.set() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
```

update
this is what iam trying to do , iam adding dbg.go_return() to go to the next breakpoint but its throwing timedout error please help if i manually press go button its going to the next breakpoint in trace32 but giving bp.go() its giving timedout error

```
data=pd.read_csv("useR1.csv")
# converting column data to list
ARG = data['Arguments'].tolist()
for i in ARG:
  mysys = dbg.symbol.query_by_name(name=i)
  bp = dbg.breakpoint.set(address=mysys.address)
dbg.go_return()  
Break
```

```
  File "c:\Users\Desktop\IT_Script\test hello.py", line 70, in <module>
    dbg.go_return()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lauterbach\trace32\rcl\rcl.py", line 429, in go_return
    self.cmd("Go.Return")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lauterbach\trace32\rcl\_rc\_command.py", line 16, in __call__
    self.__conn._cmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lauterbach\trace32\rcl\rcl.py", line 284, in _cmd
    self.__library.t32_executecommand(cmd.encode(), 4096)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lauterbach\trace32\rcl\_rc\_library.py", line 429, in t32_executecommand
    return self.generic_api_call(
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lauterbach\trace32\rcl\_rc\_library.py", line 313, in generic_api_call
    recv_data = self._link.receive()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\lauterbach\trace32\rcl\_rc\hlinknet.py", line 649, in receive
    raise ApiConnectionTimeoutError(str(e)) from None
lauterbach.trace32.rcl._rc._error.ApiConnectionTimeoutError: timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import lauterbach.trace32.rcl as t32
dbg = t32.autoconnect()
sym = dbg.symbol.query_by_name(name='ComMainFunctionTx')
print(sym)
bp = dbg.breakpoint.set(address=sym.address)
print(bp)
```

Comment: Thanks @dev15 it help very much , is it possible to take the multiple breakpoint from a csv import ? i know i have to ask in a new question , please excuse this one time.

Comment: Sure you can have a list of the symbol names in a CSV file and read them using the CSV module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: yes iam currently reading it using a loop in a list its good but in general some breakpoints will fail to set is there a way to upadte in the same csv as pass or fail ?

Comment: hi @dev15 the breakpoints are setting but the syatem is not going to the next breakpoint in breakpoint list instead its stopping at the first one  using dbg.go_return() or dbg.go() are making the error     raise ApiConnectionTimeoutError(str(e)) from None
lauterbach.trace32.rcl._rc._error.ApiConnectionTimeoutError: timed out please help

Comment: "is not going to the next breakpoint in breakpoint list instead its stopping at the first one" This is to be expected, the processor will halt at the first breakpoint, there's no breakpoint order.